# HTML table header keeps repeating for each row of table

Tags: visualforce

```
success: function( data ) {
                    response( $ac.map( data , function( item ) {
                        return {                               
                           label: '<a><table><thead><tr bgcolor="#9A9595"><th>AccName</th> <th>BillingCity</th> <th>BillingCountry</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td width="50%">'+
                            item.AccName+'</td> <td width="70%">'
                            +item.BillingCity+'</td> <td width="70%"> '+item.BillingCountry+
                            '</td></tr></tbody></table></a>',
                            value: item.AccName
                        }
                    }));
                },
```

Comment: Just glancing at this, not knowing what `data` is (is it a list?), not knowing what `$ac.map` is, I suspect the problem is `$ac.map` is is constructing a map. Since you have `<thead>` in the JSON you're returning if `data` is in fact a list and `$ac.map` is performing some kind of iteration over that list, then it would stand to reason you have a bunch of table headers. But really we need to understand what `data` and `$ac.map` are before we can really be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping over an array, which will execute your map function once per element.

You can see that your map function adds the `thead` once for each element. You need to construct the actual table outside of the map, and only build the table row markup within the function that executes once for each item. Something like:

```
    var tableHead = '<a><table><thead><tr bgcolor="#9A9595"><th>AccName</th> <th>BillingCity</th> <th>BillingCountry</th></tr></thead> <tbody>';

    var tableBody = $ac.map( data , function( item ) {
        return '<tr><td width="50%">' + item.AccName + '</td> <td width="70%">' + item.BillingCity + '</td> <td width="70%"> ' + item.BillingCountry + '</td></tr>';
    });

    var tableEnd = '</tbody></table></a>';

    var table = tableHead + tableBody + tableEnd;
```

will build you a table, but I'm not sure how it fits into your wider problem as you don't say how the consuming code uses this and what `label` and `value` are for.